# Get an array of product.id that are in the cart

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to cycle over all my product.id in my cart.
I have a various product with the same product.id but different line_item.

Example:

line.item[1]: productID 2756695130141

line.item[2]: productID 2756695130141

line.item[3]: productID 2756702765085

line.item[4]: productID 2756695130141

I want to know how many different productID I have (in this case, 2). How can I do this in Liquid/Shopify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do that is to use arrays. Because they have `map` and `unique`.

This code will return  array of unique product IDs

```
{% assign uniqueProductIdsArray= cart.items | map: 'product_id'| uniq  %}
```

This code will return concatenated string of unique product IDs

```
{% assign uniqueProductIdsString= cart.items | map: 'product_id'| uniq | join: ', ' %}
```

Documentation about `Array filters` in liquid: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters

Comment: Victor, do you have documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code may help you

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
      {{ item.id }} //This will return product id of items in cart
{% endfor %}
```

Please write back if this is not the solution you are looking for.

**EDIT**

```
{% assign uniqueProductIdsArray= cart.items | map: 'id'| uniq  %}
```

Comment: No, this isn't what I'm looking for. I need to get an array of productIDs. The solution you've posted just outputs the various IDs

Answer (score 0):

// Best and easy solution

{% for item in cart.items %}
`{{item.product.id}}`
{% endfor %}`